# is there any chance to lost TcpServer.ReceiveLn data?

Tags: delphi, networking, client-server, delphi-7, tcpserver

I need to monitor activity of my app which is executed on remote computers, so I choosed to use simple SendLn / RecieveLn method, but I'm not sure if it will be stable inside of very big local network ( one server will receive a simple text from a very big amount of computers).

```
procedure Tform1.log(inp:string);
begin
  //
  richEditText.Lines.Insert(0,inp); 
end;

procedure TForm1.TcpServer1Accept(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
  var buf:string;
begin
  //
  log('accept:'+ClientSocket.RemoteHost);
  log('accept:'+ClientSocket.Receiveln);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is never guaranteed delivery - network issues see to that. The only way that a client knows that the server has been notified is if the client receives a response from the server. However, in the case of status updates, as long as the complete status is sent in the update you can design the system so that if the odd message is lost, there is no real issue because the next message or so will eventually get through. Unless you have permanent network issues, in which case "sneakernet" is your only option ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe you misunderstood my message, I was asking about Accept method by TcpServer and ReceiveLn method which is called inside. I'm not sure how it manages threads(is it?) and all that stuff. Which effect I will get if 5 computers will try to connect and then Ttcpserver will execute accept method? Will it be executed in a same time or not?